# Как сделать событие .swipe на динамически созданный объект?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

господа. Такой вопрос, у меня есть карта yandex api на сайте.
На мобильных устройствах я хотел бы сделать исчезновение балуна по свайпу на него вниз.
Я подключил библиотеку touchswipe, у меня возник такой вопрос.
Так как балун создается динамически, то можно ли как-то событие .swipe привязать на динамический созданный объект?

```
$(".ymaps-2-1-79-balloon").swipe( {
        swipe:function(event, down, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
            $(".ymaps-2-1-79-balloon").remove() 
        },
        threshold:0
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень странное решение обращаться напрямую к DOM-объекту. В API есть собственные методы для закрытия баллуна, которые вы также можете подвязать к своему событию.

Выбор метода зависит от того, откуда вы вызываете баллун: есть [баллун карты](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/map.Balloon.html), [баллун геообъекта](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geoObject.Balloon.html), [баллун кластеризатора](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Clusterer.html#field_detail__balloon), [баллун менеджера объектов](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.Balloon.html), [баллун хотспотного слоя](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/hotspot.layer.Balloon.html) — к каждому следует обращаться через свой менеджер.

Например, если вы хотите закрыть баллун геообъекта, используйте метод менеджера:

```
geoObject.Balloon(geoObject).close();
```

и т. д.